# JS that work in Codepen doesnt work on my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

Could you explain me why this code works well in codepen, but not in my html-page. I can't even check the error that possibly appeared. I will glad your help! I suppose that error relates with connecting some jquery modules.. But I tried to fix it and connect some of them but unsuccessfully.
css and html works well. But I can't open an image

Overall, I decided to public the whole code from html-page. Unfortunately, removing the 's' character in https and replacing connection of jquery not solved the problem..

Problem solved. The reason that my code doesn't work was bootstrap. I needed to connect a special bootstrap link to my code and it solved the problem.
  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css'>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/14/enhanced/webdr01/original-9161-1439317330-3.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />

        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/14/enhanced/webdr08/original-1654-1439317465-3.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/15/enhanced/webdr08/original-13354-1439321173-3.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/15/enhanced/webdr04/original-25740-1439321209-5.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/15/enhanced/webdr08/original-9292-1439319916-3.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/14/enhanced/webdr05/original-6710-1439319334-17.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />

        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/15/enhanced/webdr02/original-16901-1439320287-3.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/15/enhanced/webdr04/original-29345-1439321306-8.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/15/enhanced/webdr15/original-20286-1439320376-10.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
    <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/14/enhanced/webdr02/original-6989-1439317507-15.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
    <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/14/enhanced/webdr11/original-8867-1439317446-6.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
    <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-08/11/14/enhanced/webdr03/original-22498-1439319085-3.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" class="gallery-img" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
   .gallery {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: 500ms;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    page-break-inside: avoid; /* For Firefox. */
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* For Chrome & friends. */
    break-inside: avoid; /* For standard browsers like IE. :-) */
}

.gallery img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal-img,.model-vid{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
.modal-body{
  padding:0px;
}

.modal-dialog {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
    top: 10%;
}

.modal-content {
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .gallery {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
    .gallery div { margin: 0;
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .gallery {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
    .gallery div {
        margin: 0;
        width: 200px;
    }
}

</style>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".gallery-img").click(function(){
    var t = $(this).attr("src");
    $(".modal-body").html("<img src='"+t+"' class='modal-img'>");
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that modal() is part of jQuery lib? Dont you need to load jqueryui or bootstrap to be able to use modal() ?

Check in your codepen settings, under javascript, you will find the libs you need to load on your html page.

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to load secure content on an insecure page. Try loading jquery using https instead: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg: Is your JQuery script tag in the `<head>` element in your HTML?

Reference | Example: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_lib_microsoft

Comment: It seems that It might be solution but, unfortunately not.